# How do I define a range and sort by number in Vim using regular expressions?

Tags: vim

This post is a two-parter.  I'm trying to sort a set of ip statements that look like:

```
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.80.1/28
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.180.1/32
...
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.1.1/32
```

by ip.  Is it possible to return a range by using a regular expression?  The following returns an error

```
%/172.*/sort n
```

and this doesn't (apparently) do anything:

```
g/172.*/sort n
```

Can this even be done?

Now, I solved the range problem directly:

```
18,31 sort
```

but this sorts in ASCII-order, not numerically (wrt the ips).

```
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.180.1/32
...
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.80.1/28
```

and unfortunately this [Vim Tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Sort_lines) tip doesn't work:

```
18,31 sort n
```

In fact, it does nothing; sorting on the original list leaves the original order intact.  So even if returning a range via regular expressions is impossible, how do I sort these lines numerically?

UPDATE
The following works:

```
18,31 !sort -n -t . -k 3,3 -k 4,4
```

(I only need to sort on the last two two bytes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a regex for the beginning line and a regex for the ending line of a range.  If you had this file:

```
foo
bar
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.80.1/28
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.55.1/28
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.180.1/28
ifconfig em0 alias 172.16.1.1/32
baz
quux
```

You could sort the lines with IP addresses like this:

```
:/172/,/baz/-1sort
```

This says "start at the first line that matches `/172/`, end one line above the first line that matches `/baz/`".  You might come up with a more clever regex depending upon your file's contents.

I don't know how to sort IP addresses in Vim in one pass.  But if you have access to GNU sort, you could do it something like this (as per [this article](http://www.madboa.com/geek/sort-addr/)):

```
:/172/,/baz/-1!sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4
```

That'll sort them numerically.  Not sure what you mean by "lexicographically" with regards to IP addresses.

Regarding `:sort` and `:g`, the Vim help at `:h :sort` says:

> Note that using ":sort" with ":global" doesn't sort the matching lines, it's quite useless.

Comment: Lexicographic is incorrect--I should have said numeric (I've edited).  Unfortunately, I thought of your range trick too but the file is just a list of ip configuration for the start_if.<interface> file used in FreeBSD; there's nothing to use as a sentinel. Otherwise everything works!